# Error: socket hang up when sending a POST request using Postman + nodemon

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, postman, nodemon

I'm writing an application using the MVC model. Each time I tried to send a POST request through Postman I cannot get a response and get a 'Error: socket hang up' message. It happened suddenly, seconds before this error occured for the first time I had sent requests without any errors. None of the answers on SO seem to solve this problem, although I know from them that Nodemon can have an influence on this behaviour. I'm running the app the port 8000. I don't even know what piece of code can be useful for explaining this question, because everything worked before.

Comment: Most probable reason would be recent changes in proxy, security or firewall settings. Try hitting the end point with telnet from the same machine this runs.